# My program crashes when performing image processing with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I use OpenCV for my school project.

All my programs works when I use the "basics" of OpenCV, but when I have to do "big" image processing - for example with findContours() or HoughLines or HoughLinesP, my program crashes...

Do you have an idea why?

Edit: The code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "lol";
    IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("frame3.jpg", 0);
    cout << "bas";

    cvWaitKey(3000);
    Mat src(image);

    Mat color_dst;
    cout << "la3";

    imshow("source", src);

    cout << "la4";
    waitKey(3000);
    cout << "la5";
    vector<Vec4i> lines;

    HoughLinesP(src, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 80, 30, 10);

    cout << "la6";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        line(color_dst, Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
            Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8);
    }

    imshow("io", color_dst);
    cvWaitKey(5000);
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: yes but i'm so put out...all the code is right but it's not working :/

Comment: dear SusuDev, just *show* the code (and the error you get) and no - you qould not be here if it was working ...

Comment: Well, unless this is an issue outside of your code, your code cannot be both right and not working at the same time. How are we supposed to tell anything here without seeing it?

Comment: ok sorry not to show my code, just 2 minutes i will re edit my post

Comment: And I have no error log, just it crashes.

Comment: on which line does it crash?

Comment: between the "cout << "la5"" and "cout << "la6"", so during the HoughLinesP...

Comment: For me this crashes on the last `imshow` because `color_dst` is never initialized to anything so you get an assertion failure in imshow for `size.width>0 && size.height>0`.

Comment: I think that the program not continue to imshow : it crashes before, it crashes before displaying "la6"

Comment: since you do not flush the output buffer (std::endl) you cannot tell when the strings are actually be shown on console

Comment: ah ok...sorry i don't know that...i will try your answer asap. thanks

Comment: [houghlinesp](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlinesp) needs a *binary input* (you got grayscale already, but that's not enough) , so throw in a threshold or Canny, etc

Comment: also, please use: `Mat src = imread("frame3.jpg", 0);`  . - and skip the pesky iplimage conversion

Comment: @SusuDev Yeah, try flushing after "la6". I compiled your code without any modifications and it goes past it before crashing with mentioned message (OpenCV 2.4.8).

Comment: thanks berak - but i open a binarised image

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot for your answers.

This morning, I've totally deleted OpenCV, then reinstalled it and created again the dependencies in Visual Studio...and it's working now !

So, i think that it was not working because I didn't setting up OpenCV very well...sorry fo losing your time...

Answer (score 1):

i think it crashes because you advise the line routine to draw a line to a image that was not constructed.

`Mat color_dest` dows not create a image buffer. Use one of the constructors with image size and type.